# Does Guice have an annotation similar to Spring's @Mandatory or @Required?

Tags: guice

Guice does not require initialization of provides methods in the modules, allowing the service to start running without these consumers initializing, which can result in major issues after an outage.

Is there a way to require this initialization - similar to @Mandatory or @Required in Spring?

If not, how would we make initialization mandatory?

The code itself probably won't add anything, but here's a general version of what we are trying to ensure initicalizes within the module itself:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
public TriggeredConsumer triggeredConsumer(variousParameters) {
    TriggeredConsumer triggeredConsumer = new TriggeredConsumer(variousParameters);

    triggeredConsumer.start();
    shutdownHook.thenRun(triggeredConsumer::stop);

    return triggeredConsumer;
}
```

Comment: 1. Provide code examples of the issues which you observe in Guice. 2. Provide explanation and/or links to what `@Mandatory` in Spring is (quick google search doesn't say that it is some official annotation).

Comment: That might explain why I was struggling to find anything, but it was something a senior engineer had advised we needed to find the Guice equivalent for.  @Required may be what he meant.

Comment: The problem is that such definition is not executed if no other class is referencing it?

Answer (score 0):

The question refers to `lazy` vs. `eager` initialisation.

```
@Provides
@Singleton
```

Is executed only, if the provided binding is requested to be injected somewhere else due to `lazy` initialisation in `DEVELOPMENT` stage.

Caused by the bug [provider methods can't bind eager singletons](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Scopes#eager-singletons) in Guice, `eager` initialisation is only  possible within the configure method of a Guice module as documented for [Eager Singletons](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Scopes#eager-singletons)

```
bind(TriggeredConsumer.class).asEagerSingleton();
```

or by creating the injector in `PRODUCTION` stage: [Phase 3: Singleton Preloading](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Bootstrap#phase-3-singleton-preloading):

```
Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(Stage.PRODUCTION, new MyGuiceModule());
```